# Passing data to controller from Kendo UI window and data is empty

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

So, im trying to pass data to the controller action and it keeps getting there as empty even though when debugging in the data is populated before the call.  Im really not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried make it a post instead of a get, ive tried not using url.action and just putting in the fully qualified path.

Here is the code from the view.

```
function openWindow() {
        var grid = $("#AjaxGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        var stringData = JSON.stringify(selectedData);

        var window = $("#UserDetailDiv").data("kendoWindow");
        var PopUpTitle = "User Detail: ";

        window.setOptions({
            title: PopUpTitle,
            content: "Loading....."
        });

        window.refresh({
            url: "@Url.Action("UserDetail", "Inquiry")",
            data: {
                userString: stringData,
                directCall: "T"
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {
                window.close();
                alert($.parseJSON(xhr.responseText));
            }
        });
        window.open();
        window.center();
    }
```

Here is the signature of the action.

```
    <ViewModelActionFilter> _
    Public Function UserDetail(userString As String, directCall As String) _
```

Comment: How is your stringData looks like ? Did you try serialize instead of stringify ? I am not seeing GET or POST in your code

Comment: telerik told me it always sends as a get. Also, i am deserializing in the method.

Comment: Try passing data like this  data = form.serialize() + '&' + $.param(directCall); and in window,refresh data: data

Comment: The issue there is the data is coming from a selected grid row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working with a post. The issue is when using the kendo window and setting iFrame:true, it blocks the post. I removed it and now it is working great.
Before:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("UserDetailDiv") _
.Title("User Details") _
.Visible(False) _
.Modal(True) _
.Height(500) _
.Draggable(True) _
.Width(900) _
.iframe(true)
```

)

After:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("UserDetailDiv") _
.Title("User Details") _
.Visible(False) _
.Modal(True) _
.Height(500) _
.Draggable(True) _
.Width(900)
```

)

Refresh code:

```
        function openDetailWindow() {
        var grid = $("#AjaxGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        var stringData = JSON.stringify(selectedData);

        var window = $("#UserDetailDiv").data("kendoWindow");
        var PopUpTitle = "User Detail: ";

        window.setOptions({
            title: PopUpTitle,
            content: "Loading....."
        });

        window.refresh({
        url: "../Inquiry/UserDetail",
        type: "POST",
        data: { userData: stringData, directCall: "T" }
        });
        window.open();
        window.center();
    }
```